# highchart treemap parent label as tile

Tags: highcharts, label, treemap

I have a highchart treemap with three level(parent and child, descendent), what i want is :

1-see parent label as tile in their section

2- show all levels label in first load that are created by formatter
you can see somthing like that in this lib:

[react-charts/treemap-series](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-charts/treemap-series/)
i tried to change ui of parent label, but after setting background color, it overlap on childs in small tiles

Comment: This config is not working for me, please prepare working example based on this template: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0zdtc1La/2/)

Comment: based on your example, how can i show the parent label in first load and make sure it not  overlap on it's child labels

Answer (score 0):

To control showing datalables you can use [levels.dataLabels](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.levels.dataLabels).

```
levels: [{
  level: 1,
  layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    style: {
      fontSize: '15px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }
}, 
    {
  level: 2,
  layoutAlgorithm: 'sliceAndDice',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    style: {
      fontSize: '15px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  }
}],
```

You may also use [series.treemap.data.dataLabels](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.data.dataLabels) for setting datalables for each series.

```
data: [{
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  id: 'A',
  name: 'Apples',
  color: "red"
}, {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  id: 'B',
  name: 'Bananas',
  color: "yellow"
}, {
  id: 'O',
  name: 'Oranges',
  color: 'orange'
}, {
  name: 'Anne',
  parent: 'A',
  value: 5
}, {
  name: 'Rick',
  parent: 'A',
  value: 3
}, {
  name: 'Peter',
  parent: 'A',
  value: 4
}, {
  name: 'Anne',
  parent: 'B',
  value: 4,
  color: 'black'
}, {
  name: 'Rick',
  parent: 'B',
  value: 10
}, {
  name: 'Peter',
  parent: 'B',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Anne',
  parent: 'O',
  value: 1
}, {
  name: 'Rick',
  parent: 'O',
  value: 3
}, {
  name: 'Peter',
  parent: 'O',
  value: 3
}, {
  name: 'Susanne',
  parent: 'Kiwi',
  value: 2,
  color: 'green'
}]
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hat4nob2/2/

Comment: as you can see in my code i already used formatter and data label but not getting desired result

Comment: for example i want to show all levels labels at first load

Comment: So for this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hat4nob2/3/), you would still need to render the labels with [Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label).

Comment: i changed my question to be more clear, can you see that